# How to include wordpress plugins files

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two wordpress plugin folders and two files like so:

`/my-plugin/folder1/file1.php` and `my-plugin/folder2/file2.php`

How to include one file1.php into the file2.php?

I used this code in file2.php

```
include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/folder1/file1.php');
```

but it returned an error.

Comment: What error? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `plugin_dir_path()`, can not be use like this with your file and folder configuration.

It returns an error because the file is not found.

```
plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)
```

Will get the filesystem directory path (with trailing slash) for the plugin `__FILE__` passed in (file2.php in your case).

In your case, in file2.php, it will return : `/path/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/folder2/folder1/file1.php`

The workaround:

In the main plugin file, you can add a `define` constant

```
defined('MYPLUGIN_DIR') or define('MYPLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ));
```

Now `MYPLUGIN_DIR` is available in any file.
In file2.php:

```
include_once( MYPLUGIN_DIR . 'folder1/file1.php');
```

Will return : `/path/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/folder1/file1.php`

Hope it helps !

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot, brother! :)